# Schedule a Reboot if there is a change in file version

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have a MSI package, which installs a Driver, however the Uninstall of the driver require a Reboot. for which I had scheduled a Standard Custom Actions (`scheduleReboot`) after `InstallFinilize`, which works fine.

Now I would like to Schedule reboot only if I am  replacing the "driver" file. is there any way of determining "Installed file version" and the "to be installed file version" and based on compassion, if there is a change, schedule reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the Windows Installer can determine whether a [system restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/10117d2c-c2c8-456f-9fce-a89c2d69d3c1) is necessary. For example, the [ScheduleReboot action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/36f24f57-f1f0-4eca-9b6d-1b25fb73fa96) can be used to force the installer to prompt for a restart after installing drivers that require a restart. If the installer attempts to replace files that are in use, it automatically prompts the user to restart even if ScheduleReboot has not been used. The [ForceReboot action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/e1bcdd59-8cbc-46f7-b908-c8cbc2ea0539) must always be used with a conditional statement such that the installer triggers a restart only when necessary. For example, a restart may only be required if a particular file is replaced or a particular component is installed.

Each product installation is unique and a custom action may be required to determine whether a restart is needed. There are tables in the Windows installer database which you and use for [Searching for Existing Applications, Files, Registry Entries or .ini File Entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/a78ca652-c730-4231-80f2-60cf0bad5b02) and to set a property.

Note: When [Replacing Existing Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/8be734c7-4f16-4f54-93db-bb8efb1ea6da), Windows Installer determines whether the component's key file is already installed before attempting to install the files of any component. If the installer finds a file with the same name as the component's key file installed in the target location, it compares the version, date, and language of the two key files and uses file versioning rules to determine whether to install the component provided by the package. If the installer determines it needs to replace the component base upon the key file, then it uses the file versioning rules on each installed file to determine whether to replace the file.